# My JUnit test gives me several errors that dont have anything to do with them and i dont know how to fix it

Tags: java, junit

So i was doing so programming for school. I came across this assignment, which want the following:

> Pre:  The next lines retrieved bysccontains a textual representationof a House.
>
> Post:  Transforms the textual representation of the House into a Houseobject.
>
> Hint:  Make use of thereadmethod inAddress

We also need to create some JUnit tests with it. The problem is that my tests give me an error but i dont know what i am doing wrong.

[image]

I think my JUnit test is wrong, because i just copy pasted it from the previous assignment and changed some values. It says something with inputmismatchException, so i commented out the throw ioexception but this still didnt change anything. What am i doing wrong?

This is my read house and tostring method, note that i commented out my IOException because i thought that was causing it.

```
    public static House read(Scanner sc)  { //throws IOException
    Address address = Address.read(sc);
    int nRooms = sc.nextInt();
    int salePrice = sc.nextInt();

    House House = new House(address, nRooms, salePrice);
    return House;

/**
 * String representation of the house
 */
public String toString() {
    String address = this.address +"";
            String nRooms = this.nRooms + "";
    
    
    
    String House = address +", "+ nRooms + ", " + salePrice;
    return House;
```

This is my Address read and tostring method:

```
public static Address read(Scanner sc) {
    
    
    
    Address address = new Address(sc.next(), sc.next(), sc.next(), sc.next());
    return address;
}

/**
 * String representation of the object Address
 */
public String toString() {
street = street + " ";
number = number +" ";
zipCode = zipCode +" ";

    String address = street + number + zipCode +  city;
    return address;
}
```

This is my JUnit test for the read method of house

```
@Test
    //
    public void testHouseRead() {
        String input = "Janstraat 1 2324VK Leiden, 4, 250000";
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        String test = House.read(sc).toString();
        assertEquals(input, test);
    }
```

Comment: Don't post images of errors. Paste the text. Your IDE should have it in a text format somewhere, but if you really can't find that, run your tests at the command line.

Comment: Since we dont use main methods at school i couldnt use the console. I tried to copy the lines that were showing the error but i couldnt select them

Comment: You can run jUnit tests in the console. Find out how.

Comment: Hint: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt-- "InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range"

Comment: That will be somethign for later then..

Comment: Hmm already saw this but i cant find where i translated or even if i translated my nextInt in read House

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an `InputMismatchException`.

It's being thrown by `Scanner.throwFor()` in the chain of calls `Scanner.nextInt()` calling `Scanner.nextInt()` calling `Scanner.next()` calling `Scanner.throwFor()`.

Your code calls `Scanner.nextInt()`, so you should look at the JavaDoc documentation for that, to see whether it tells you under what circumstances an `InputMismatchException` is thrown.

> `public int nextInt()`
>
> Scans the next token of the input as an int. An
>   invocation of this method of the form nextInt() behaves in exactly the
>   same way as the invocation nextInt(radix), where radix is the default
>   radix of this scanner.
>
> **Returns:**
>
> the int scanned from the input
>
> **Throws:**
>
> **InputMismatchException** - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range
>
> **NoSuchElementException** - if input is exhausted
>
> **IllegalStateException** - if this scanner is closed

So, "the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range".

Line 79 of `House.java` is calling `Scanner.readInt()` and the `Scanner` is not finding an integer.

Scanner splits the input using whitespace by default. `Address.read()` consumes the first four tokens. The fifth token is `"4,"`. This doesn't match the *integer* pattern described by the `Scanner` docs.

Comment: Aside: I really don't know why so many beginners' Java courses make such heavy use of `Scanner`.

Comment: hmm, i thought about this and i addes 4 empty tokens to  the House read method. 2 between address address and nrooms and 2 between nrooms and saleprice, since there is a , and a whitespace between them. But now i get a different error. Its a >NosuchElementException. Even though i never threw an exception  because i thought those were causing my error in the first place

Comment: On your side note: Its because he wants us to build us something like an app afterwards were we ask for user input, but all just in the console

Comment: Yes but `Scanner` is by no means the only way to read terminal input.

Comment: You're not focussing on the problem described, which is that `4,` is not a number (because of the comma)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Javadoc for Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). `Scanner` uses whitespaces as delimiters as default whereas your input string is `Janstraat 1 2324VK Leiden, 4, 250000`. So one of the values you try to read in as `int` will be `4,` which clearly is no number.

Comment: i added some empty tokens between them because someone else answering my question also said this. I did this by putting 4x sc.next(), 2x between address and nRooms and 2x between nrooms and price, and i got another error. NoSuchElementException